# How to only display one option when there are multiple with the same name in PHP dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a ticket website for a festival, on my site I have created a series of dropdowns to select Ticket Type (VIP, standard etc.) and I have linked this to a PHP database, however when I add in multiple VIP tickets into the database then multiple "VIP" options appear on the dropdown. How do I only ensure that one "VIP" comes up? Here is my code below.

```php
<div class="dropdownform tickets" style="width:250px; margin-left:25px;"> 
  <?php 

  $dbConn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  mysqli_select_db($dbConn, 'festival');

  $sql = "SELECT Ticket_Type FROM tickets WHERE Days_of_entry='Saturday' ORDER BY Days_of_entry ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);

  echo "<select id='Ticket_Type' name='name'>";
  echo "<option selected>Select a Ticket Type</option>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Ticket_Type'] . "'>" . $row['Ticket_Type'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";

  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Ticket_Type FROM ...`

Comment: Why are you adding the same value to the DB multiple times? It appears you have a missing relationship here. You should have a "ticket_types" and a "tickets" table that have a relationship through a JOIN. Your select should then pull data from "ticket_types".

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT in your query for fetching data,  which will return only distinct values.